# How to look at asp.net .cshtml files in browser?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor

[image: Screenshot of file structure]

I've never touched asp.net or .cshtml files before. I have provided the file structure. What do I have to do to run the files and view them in my browser like I would with regular html files and live server on vs code? Do I need to write a script?

I tried opening it with live server, making an express server file, running dotnet watch run and dotnet run in the terminal after installing the necessary asp.net files, and dragging and dropping the files on to my browser but all that came up was the code.

Comment: You will have to share the entire code base somewhere for others to verify what exactly is the project type, ASP.NET 4.x MVC or something else. Without that, not much to be discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, be it MOST web pages with code behind, opening the source code page or file means next to nothing.

You need to be running a web server, and one that can consume + run the code behind. When that code runs, then a page is spit out with standard HTML, but those pages have LITTLE use by just opening. You need a working + running web server for those pages to work.

Thankfully, Visual Studio has a built in web server when you install it.

So, to view that page?

you have to open it from/with Visual studio. You can then hit f5, and the code will compile, then IIS (the web server) will be launched, then the .net code behind will run, render the page, and spit out standard HTML.

however, those aspx pages, or cshtml pages? They don't work alone, they required a web server, and one that can run + consume the aspx, or cshtml page. Only have the .net code has run, and THEN can the web server in question render the page, and then crank out standard HTML compatible pages that work on any computer.

So, you need visual studio here. And you then open that page with VS, and then you can say start debugging and run the page by hitting F5.

You need to open the project here - not just the one page.